# Add columns to a datatable in c#?

Tags: c#, datatable, addition, dynamic

I have a csv reader class that reads a `.csv` file and its values.... I have created `datatable` out of it... Consider my `Datatable` contains three header columns `Name,EmailId,PhoneNo`.... The values have been added successfully.... Now i want to add two columns `IsDeleted,CreatedDate` to this `datatable`... I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work,

```
    foreach (string strHeader in headers)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(strHeader);
    }
    string[] data;
    while ((data = reader.GetCSVLine()) != null)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(data);
    }
    dt.Columns.Add("IsDeleted", typeof(byte));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CreatedDate", typeof(DateTime)));
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        dr["IsDeleted"] = Convert.ToByte(0);
        dr["CreatedDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

`dt.Rows.Add(dr);` shows an error saying `This row already belongs to this table.`
....

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1273560975016964800.jpg](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1273560975016964800.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dt.Rows.Import, or dt.ImportRows, I forgot the name

or judging from your code, why you need the dt.Rows.Add? shouldn't that be omitted?

Comment: @Micheal where should i import?

Comment: @Pandiya: at first glance I thought you are copying from one datatable to another datatable.  anyway, check my edited answer

Answer (score 3):

Why do you add the datarow again into the table?

Remove the line `dt.Rows.Add(dr);`

and edit the datatable directly like this `dt.Rows[i]["IsDeleted"] = Convert.ToByte(0);` using a for loop